# Phrasing of an instragram post

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, grammaticality

I have an account on Instagram. It’s everything about hair, like new haircuts or new hairstyles and I want to say something like this to make followers send their photos to me so I can post it on my page.

> DM or tag us to share anything new about your hair

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok (I'd say hairstyle).

I'd be more specific, though. For example, you could say "You can share with our community how your new hairstyle looks through DM or tagging".

Comment: It's not necessary to qualify an answer by saying you are not a native speaker.  Answers should be correct or incorrect on their own merit.  In any case I agree Stranger's sentence is fine, especially on an informal site like Instagram, where few people use full sentences, much less formal language.  Your sentence is also fine, but might seem stiff and awkward on social media.

Comment: Also, requests for proofreading are expressly off-topic. Please don't answer questions that essentially ask, "Is this sentence okay?" We don't want to devolve into a proofreading service.